PostgreSQL column reference "employeenumber" is ambiguous
Does anyone have any idea why I get the error? I use t for which I receive, old to compare and up are the new or modified data equally to compare with the old ones. Why do I keep getting the ambiguity error? I can't think of anything anymore Help please. I'm calling it from .net using C# but the error comes from PostgreSQL.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sync_employee_data(inserts jsonb)
RETURNS TABLE
(
    employeenumber   TEXT,
    firstname        TEXT,
    lastname         TEXT,
    entrydate        DATE,
    exitdate         DATE,
    city             TEXT,
    country          TEXT,
    description      TEXT,
    gender           TEXT,
    birthday         DATE,
    mobilephone      TEXT,
    phone            TEXT,
    email            TEXT,
    street           TEXT,
    district         TEXT,
    postalcode       TEXT,
    is_deleted       BOOLEAN,
    startcontract    DATE,
    endcontract      DATE,
    fte              NUMERIC,
    departamento     TEXT,
    flag             BOOLEAN,
    ischangework     BOOLEAN,
    oldtipoempleado  TEXT,
    tipoempleado     TEXT,
    changeindicator  INT
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    WITH 
    -- 1) Convierte JSONB en filas, alias "te"
    te AS (
        SELECT 
            -- Usamos "record" como alias para la función jsonb_array_elements
            (record->>'EmployeeNumber')            AS t_employeenumber,
            (record->>'FirstName')                 AS t_firstname,
            (record->>'LastName')                  AS t_lastname,
            (record->>'EntryDate')::DATE           AS t_entrydate,
            (record->>'ExitDate')::DATE            AS t_exitdate,
            (record->>'City')                      AS t_city,
            (record->>'Country')                   AS t_country,
            (record->>'Description')               AS t_description,
            (record->>'Gender')                    AS t_gender,
            (record->>'Birthday')::DATE            AS t_birthday,
            (record->>'MobilePhone')               AS t_mobilephone,
            (record->>'Phone')                     AS t_phone,
            (record->>'Email')                     AS t_email,
            (record->>'Street')                    AS t_street,
            (record->>'District')                  AS t_district,
            (record->>'PostalCode')                AS t_postalcode,
            (record->>'StartContract')::DATE       AS t_startcontract,
            (record->>'EndContract')::DATE         AS t_endcontract,
            (record->>'FTE')::NUMERIC              AS t_fte,
            (record->>'Departamento')              AS t_departamento,
            (record->>'TipoEmpleado')              AS t_tipoempleado,

            CASE 
                WHEN (record->>'ExitDate') IS NULL 
                     OR (record->>'ExitDate') = '9999-12-31T00:00:00' 
                THEN TRUE 
                ELSE FALSE 
            END AS t_is_deleted

        FROM jsonb_array_elements(inserts) AS record
    ),

    -- 2) Trae datos "viejos" de la tabla employee, alias "od"
    od AS (
        SELECT
            e.employeenumber       AS old_employeenumber,
            e.departamento         AS old_departamento,
            e.entrydate            AS old_entrydate,
            e.exitdate             AS old_exitdate
        FROM public.employee AS e
        RIGHT JOIN te
               ON e.employeenumber = te.t_employeenumber
    ),

    -- 3) Upsert principal, alias "ue"
    ue AS (
        INSERT INTO public.employee AS e
        (
            employeenumber,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            entrydate,
            exitdate,
            city,
            country,
            description,
            gender,
            birthday,
            mobilephone,
            phone,
            email,
            street,
            district,
            postalcode,
            is_deleted,
            createdat,
            createdby,
            startcontract,
            endcontract,
            fte,
            departamento,
            tipoempleado
        )
        SELECT
            te.t_employeenumber,
            te.t_firstname,
            te.t_lastname,
            te.t_entrydate,
            te.t_exitdate,
            te.t_city,
            te.t_country,
            te.t_description,
            te.t_gender,
            te.t_birthday,
            te.t_mobilephone,
            te.t_phone,
            te.t_email,
            te.t_street,
            te.t_district,
            te.t_postalcode,
            te.t_is_deleted,
            NOW(),          -- createdat
            'SISTEMA',      -- createdby
            te.t_startcontract,
            te.t_endcontract,
            te.t_fte,
            te.t_departamento,
            te.t_tipoempleado
        FROM te

        ON CONFLICT (employeenumber)
        DO UPDATE
        SET
            firstname       = EXCLUDED.firstname,
            lastname        = EXCLUDED.lastname,
            entrydate       = EXCLUDED.entrydate,
            exitdate        = EXCLUDED.exitdate,
            city            = EXCLUDED.city,
            country         = EXCLUDED.country,
            description     = EXCLUDED.description,
            gender          = EXCLUDED.gender,
            birthday        = EXCLUDED.birthday,
            mobilephone     = EXCLUDED.mobilephone,
            phone           = EXCLUDED.phone,
            email           = EXCLUDED.email,
            street          = EXCLUDED.street,
            district        = EXCLUDED.district,
            postalcode      = EXCLUDED.postalcode,
            is_deleted      = EXCLUDED.is_deleted,
            modifiedat      = NOW(),
            modifiedby      = 'SISTEMA',
            startcontract   = EXCLUDED.startcontract,
            endcontract     = EXCLUDED.endcontract,
            fte             = EXCLUDED.fte,
            departamento    = EXCLUDED.departamento,

            -- Si la descripción cambia, ischangework = TRUE
            ischangework    = (e.description IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.description),

            -- Guardar el tipo anterior
            oldtipoempleado = e.tipoempleado,

            -- Actualizar al nuevo tipo
            tipoempleado    = EXCLUDED.tipoempleado

        WHERE
              e.firstname      IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.firstname
           OR e.lastname       IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.lastname
           OR e.entrydate      IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.entrydate
           OR e.exitdate       IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.exitdate
           OR e.city           IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.city
           OR e.country        IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.country
           OR e.description    IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.description
           OR e.gender         IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.gender
           OR e.birthday       IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.birthday
           OR e.mobilephone    IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.mobilephone
           OR e.phone          IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.phone
           OR e.email          IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.email
           OR e.street         IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.street
           OR e.district       IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.district
           OR e.postalcode     IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.postalcode
           OR e.is_deleted     IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.is_deleted
           OR e.startcontract  IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.startcontract
           OR e.endcontract    IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.endcontract
           OR e.fte            IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.fte
           OR e.departamento   IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.departamento
           OR e.tipoempleado   IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.tipoempleado

        RETURNING
            e.employeenumber    AS up_employeenumber,
            e.firstname         AS up_firstname,
            e.lastname          AS up_lastname,
            e.entrydate         AS up_entrydate,
            e.exitdate          AS up_exitdate,
            e.city              AS up_city,
            e.country           AS up_country,
            e.description       AS up_description,
            e.gender            AS up_gender,
            e.birthday          AS up_birthday,
            e.mobilephone       AS up_mobilephone,
            e.phone             AS up_phone,
            e.email             AS up_email,
            e.street            AS up_street,
            e.district          AS up_district,
            e.postalcode        AS up_postalcode,
            e.is_deleted        AS up_is_deleted,
            e.startcontract     AS up_startcontract,
            e.endcontract       AS up_endcontract,
            e.fte               AS up_fte,
            e.departamento      AS up_departamento,

            -- Flag: TRUE => hubo update, FALSE => insert
            CASE 
                WHEN e.modifiedby IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE
                ELSE FALSE
            END AS up_flag,

            e.ischangework      AS up_ischangework,
            e.oldtipoempleado   AS up_oldtipoempleado,
            e.tipoempleado      AS up_tipoempleado
    )

    -- 4) SELECT final uniendo "ue" con "od"
    SELECT
        ue.up_employeenumber    AS employeenumber,
        ue.up_firstname         AS firstname,
        ue.up_lastname          AS lastname,
        ue.up_entrydate         AS entrydate,
        ue.up_exitdate          AS exitdate,
        ue.up_city              AS city,
        ue.up_country           AS country,
        ue.up_description       AS description,
        ue.up_gender            AS gender,
        ue.up_birthday          AS birthday,
        ue.up_mobilephone       AS mobilephone,
        ue.up_phone             AS phone,
        ue.up_email             AS email,
        ue.up_street            AS street,
        ue.up_district          AS district,
        ue.up_postalcode        AS postalcode,
        ue.up_is_deleted        AS is_deleted,
        ue.up_startcontract     AS startcontract,
        ue.up_endcontract       AS endcontract,
        ue.up_fte               AS fte,
        ue.up_departamento      AS departamento,
        ue.up_flag              AS flag,
        ue.up_ischangework      AS ischangework,
        ue.up_oldtipoempleado   AS oldtipoempleado,
        ue.up_tipoempleado      AS tipoempleado,

        CASE 
            WHEN od.old_employeenumber IS NULL THEN 0  -- 0 => registro nuevo
            ELSE
                CASE 
                  -- 1 => Solo cambió departamento
                  WHEN 
                    (od.old_departamento IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_departamento)
                    AND (od.old_entrydate IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ue.up_entrydate)
                    AND (od.old_exitdate  IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ue.up_exitdate)
                  THEN 1

                  -- 2 => Solo cambió entryDate
                  WHEN 
                    (od.old_departamento IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ue.up_departamento)
                    AND (od.old_entrydate IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_entrydate)
                    AND (od.old_exitdate  IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ue.up_exitdate)
                  THEN 2

                  -- 3 => Solo cambió exitDate
                  WHEN 
                    (od.old_departamento IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ue.up_departamento)
                    AND (od.old_entrydate IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ue.up_entrydate)
                    AND (od.old_exitdate  IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_exitdate)
                  THEN 3

                  -- 4 => Cambió departamento + entryDate (NO exitDate)
                  WHEN 
                    (od.old_departamento IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_departamento)
                    AND (od.old_entrydate IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_entrydate)
                    AND (od.old_exitdate  IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ue.up_exitdate)
                  THEN 4

                  -- 5 => Cambió departamento + exitDate (NO entryDate)
                  WHEN 
                    (od.old_departamento IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_departamento)
                    AND (od.old_entrydate IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ue.up_entrydate)
                    AND (od.old_exitdate  IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_exitdate)
                  THEN 5

                  -- 6 => Cambió entryDate + exitDate (NO departamento)
                  WHEN 
                    (od.old_departamento IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ue.up_departamento)
                    AND (od.old_entrydate IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_entrydate)
                    AND (od.old_exitdate  IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_exitdate)
                  THEN 6

                  -- 7 => Cambió departamento + entryDate + exitDate
                  WHEN 
                    (od.old_departamento IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_departamento)
                    AND (od.old_entrydate IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_entrydate)
                    AND (od.old_exitdate  IS DISTINCT FROM ue.up_exitdate)
                  THEN 7

                  -- 8 => Se actualizó, pero no encaja en las combinaciones anteriores
                  ELSE 8
                END
        END AS changeindicator

    FROM ue
    LEFT JOIN od
           ON ue.up_employeenumber = od.old_employeenumber;

END;
$$;


As I mentioned, I already tried with aliases, employeenumber is the name that the column in the employee table has so I can't think of anything else :( that solution was to not add any more columns to the table and simply return that new data "changeIndicator".

I see possible ambiguity at line: ON CONFLICT (employeenumber)  try to define e.employeenumber

In PostgreSQL, the ON CONFLICT clause does not allow the table alias to be used in the column list or in the index name (or constraint) that is specified

It's really a bug in PL/pgSQL. There is no ambiguity, the scope of the conflict target in an UPSERT is separate from the scope of function variables.

Primarily, employenumber is the name of the first field of your output structure. Anywhere inside this function, it's visible as an unassigned variable which happens to share the name with public.employee.employenumber in your query.
The error message detail is trying to point you in that direction:

ERROR:  column reference "employeenumber" is ambiguous
LINE 106:         ON CONFLICT (employeenumber)
                              ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.


A few ways to work around this:
demo at db<>fiddle

You can avoid the conflict by using a special command #variable_conflict before begin:
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
#variable_conflict use_column
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY--...

Refer to  41.11. PL/pgSQL under the Hood: 41.11.1. Variable Substitution for more details.
ON CONFLICT won't let you use explicit e.employeenumber in its base syntax, as initially suggested by @num8er. However, if you wrap it in additional parentheses, it will accept it as an expression and infer the right constraint just fine:
ON CONFLICT ((e.employeenumber))


As already pointed out by @Laurenz Albe, you can also look up the constraint on employeenumber and use the more specific syntax:
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT the_constraint_on_employeenumber


It would have to be cascaded to all calls to this function and it's the most invasive overall, but you could also rename the output table columns to remove the conflict entirely:
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sync_employee_data(jsonb);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sync_employee_data(inserts jsonb)
RETURNS TABLE
(
    out_employeenumber   TEXT,




The conflict is caused by ON CONFLICT (employeenumber). You can use one of the following workarounds:

Qualify the column name with the table:
INSERT INTO public.employee ...
ON CONFLICT ((employee.employeenumber))
DO UPDATE ...

Thanks to Zegarek for pointing out the necessity to use double parentheses!

Use the constraint name instead:
INSERT INTO public.employee ...
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT employee_employeenumber_key
DO UPDATE ...

Replace employee_employeenumber_key with the name of the unique constraint on employeenumber.


